# WebSphere ND 8.5 Profiles

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I was looking for the complete or at least the mechanics of different profiles that can be created in WebSphere Profiles Management Tool (i'm not talking about different DISTRIBUTIONS like "express"/"for developer"/"ND" etc).

I could not find any relevant information about Developer profile, that is what I'm focusing. The only thing I found is in [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_manageprofiles.html).

Can someone tell me more about the differences (provide links plz) between then? (standard x developer x production)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tprf_tuneappserv_script.html) breaks down the differences in performance settings per tuning template. One of the larger differences between development and the other tuning profiles is that the server is configured in [development mode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rappsvr.html) which starts the server faster by disabling some settings that improve production performance.

Comment: Maybe you don't know but... in the first link on Data Source Prepared Statement Cache Size section, the developer part is "blank"... what does it means (that developer profile does not support Data Source?)?